# Play Licensing library for 2 apps

Tags: android

Suppose I have 2 paid Android apps published: A and B

Can I use Play Licensing library in my app A to check if user bought app B?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits what you're trying to achieve, but you could just check if they have app B installed on the device.

Comment: @Marcelo I'm not sure that will be the case for him considering he probably wants to give in app permissions if you own the other and if you have one app installed on your phone and one on say your tablet and you don't want to get both on your phone or vice versa, then it would be very useful for the users of his apps to just check licensing, but I'll upvote for a nice idea.

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 I understand my suggestion is pretty limited, but considering that the licensing library is based on an app specific licensing key, even if both apps are from the same developer I don't think there's a way to do that

Comment: Heres a new suggestion: If you have your own server you can use Google play services to grab the name and person ID and then add it to a list on your server and when you login on another device it checks if your name and ID is already on your server.

Comment: I want to check if app B was ever bought by user, even if it is not installed. I think license key is per account. My question is if Licensing lib allows it. I am not looking for workaounds